# Riak connection from Erlang shell

Tags: erlang, riak, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

How can i connect to riak from erlang shell.

I followed this site "https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client" but can't figured it out. please help me to connect to riak from erlang shell.

I don't know how to give the path to it

```
erl -pa $PATH_TO_RIAKC/ebin $PATH_TO_RIAKC/deps/*/ebin
```

Comment: Have You downloaded and installed riak-erlang-client?

Comment: yes i have did it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved. For future guests:
Riak needs to be downloaded and installed through make file with

```
$ git clone git://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client.git 
$ cd riak-erlang-client 
$ make
```

Comment: can you suggest me over this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612059/erlang-mapreduce-on-riak-database-giving-exception]